# How do I find out why my phone is locking up?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, performance, system-freeze

My Samsung Captivate (Galaxy S series) locks up about once per day, where the screen is frozen and it doesn't respond to any type of input. There's no pattern concerning what app I'm running at the time.  How do I find out what is causing it?

I'm running a 2.3.4-based custom ROM (Apex specifically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue has to do with installing a ROM over another one without wiping.  My particular ROM is [Apex 9.3](http://apexromcaptivate.weebly.com/apex-9x---jvr.html).  According to the associated [XDA forum thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16532066&postcount=7351), freezing problems with this ROM have been solved by *"a complete wipe including formatting sdcard, system, cache and data when flashing 9.0"*.

I have done so, wiping the data and cache in recovery mode, reinstalled the ROM, and I have gone a week without a severe lockup (severe meaning I have to restart the phone to get out of it).  I've had an occasional 5 second freeze or so, but that's it.

**Update:**  Still had issues with freeze-ups.  Turned out it was the ROM.  Went to a new ROM and have not experienced freezes.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing (uninstalling) custom apps you installed in batches, and using the phone for a day or two.

Also try removing SD card if you have one. Sometimes SD card causes this, either because of faulty connection with the card or because it makes the connection to battery lose.

It is a slow method and requires patience, but is bound to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with my Samsung Galaxy S and the Australian Samsung HO say there's nothing wrong with the phone.  I've been trying to get it fixed since July, but they won't do anything to fix it.  I think there's a fault in the phone that makes the screen freeze over - only thing you can do is turn it off, take the battery pack and SIM card out, then completely reboot it.  I reckon the screen is going to die.

Comment: How do you reboot it when it gets locked up?  Is there a button combo you can press?